# How to create a multi-dimensional dictionary/object in python

Tags: python, object, dictionary, web-scraping

I have this object:

```
"products":[
   {
      "title":"ASUS ZenFone 4 Max",
      "author":"1",
      "date":"2017-12-17 21:49:30",
      "date_gmt":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "content":"",
      "status":"draft",
      "comment_status":"open",
      "image":"",
      "gallery":[

      ],
      "meta":{
         "post_views_count":"0",
         "aps-product-price":"0",
         "aps-product-sku":"SKU",
         "aps-product-stock":"InStock",
         "aps-product-qty":"0",
         "aps-product-on-sale":"no",
         "aps-product-sale-price":"0",
         "aps-product-sale-start":"",
         "aps-product-sale-end":"",
         "aps-product-features":[
            {
               "name":"CPU",
               "icon":"cpu",
               "value":"CPU Feature"
            },
            {
               "name":"RAM",
               "icon":"ram",
               "value":"RAM Feature"
            },
            {
               "name":"Storage",
               "icon":"hdd",
               "value":"Storage Feature"
            },
            {
               "name":"Display",
               "icon":"display",
               "value":"Display Feature"
            },
            {
               "name":"Camera",
               "icon":"camera",
               "value":"Camera Feature"
            },
            {
               "name":"OS",
               "icon":"cog",
               "value":"OS Feature"
            }
         ],
         "aps-product-videos":[

         ],
         "aps-attr-group-684":{
            "618":"General-Model-Attribute",
            "556":"01-12-2017",
            "644":"02-12-2017",
            "659":"Available"
         },
         "aps-attr-group-685":{
            "578":"Design-Dimensions-Attribute",
            "678":"Design-Weight-Attribute",
            "572":"*Design-Colors-Attribute\r\n*Design-Colors-Attribute\r\n*Design-Colors-Attribute"
         },
         "aps-attr-group-687":{
            "655":"Display-Dimensions-Attribute",
            "861":"Display-Technology-Attribute",
            "581":"Display-Protection-Attribute",
            "645":"Display-Resolution-Attribute"
         },
         "aps-attr-group-690":{
            "623":"Software-Operating System-Attribute",
            "668":"Software-User Interface-Attribute"
         },
         "aps-attr-group-689":{
            "631":"Camera-Front-Attribute",
            "590":"Camera-Front-Camera-Features-Attribute",
            "647":"Camera-Rear-Camera-Attribute",
            "863":"Camera-Rear-Camera-Features-Attribute"
         },
         "aps-attr-group-691":{
            "571":"Hardware-Chipset-Attribute",
            "573":"Hardware-CPU-Attribute",
            "596":"Hardware-GPU-Attribute",
            "639":"512 MB",
            "612":"Hardware-InternalStorage-Attribute",
            "570":"Hardware-CardSlot-Attribute",
            "651":"Hardware-Sensors-Attribute"
         },
         "aps-attr-group-686":{
            "553":"Network-Networks-Attribute",
            "654":"Network-SIM-Attribute"
         },
         "aps-attr-group-692":{
            "564":"Connectivity-Bluetooth-Attribute",
            "679":"Connectivity-WiFi-Attribute",
            "680":"No",
            "666":"Connectivity-USB-Attribute",
            "595":"Connectivity-GPS-Attribute",
            "621":"No"
         },
         "aps-attr-group-688":{
            "558":"Media-AudioPlayback-Attribute",
            "672":"Media-Video-Playback-Attribute",
            "671":"Media-Video-Out-Attribute",
            "593":"Media-FMRADIO-Attribute",
            "555":"Media-Alert-Types-Attribute",
            "646":"Media-Ring-Tones-Attribute",
            "615":"Media-Loudspeaker-Attribute",
            "598":"Media-Handsfree-Attribute"
         },
         "aps-attr-group-695":{
            "569":"Battery-Capacity-Attribute",
            "629":"Removable",
            "862":"Battery-Charging-Attribute",
            "658":"Battery-Standby-Attribute",
            "662":"Battery-TalkTime-Attribute",
            "620":"Battery-MusicPlay-Attribute"
         },
         "aps-product-offers":[

         ],
         "aps-product-rating":{
            "design":5,
            "display":6,
            "camera":5,
            "performance":5,
            "battery":6
         },
         "aps-product-rating-total":"5.4",
         "aps-custom-tabs":[

         ],
         "_disable_fbc":"",
         "_yoast_wpseo_primary_aps-cats":"",
         "_yoast_wpseo_content_score":"30"
      },
      "terms":{
         "aps-cats":[
            "smartphones"
         ]
      }
   },...]
```

and I need to achieve this dynamically in a loop. Ex:

```
#Initial declaration
products = {"products":{}}

#Add items in the products object
products["title"] = "ASUS ZenFone 4 Max"
products["author"] = "1"

for items in product_list:
    products["meta"]["post_views_count"] = 0
    products["meta"]["aps-product-sku"] = "SKU"
```

I can't seem to figure out how to add the next product which also has "title", "author", "meta" (this is also an object that has key-value pair as well) etc.

I hope you can understand my query. I'm currently doing web scraping :)

Thank you

Comment: What does product_list look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
products = []
product1 = {}
product1["title"] = "ASUS ZenFone 4 Max"

product2 = {}
product2["title"] = "Galaxy S8"

products.append(product1)
products.append(product2)

print(products)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

new_list = list()
new_product_dict = {
  "title":"new title",
  "author":"new author",
  "date":"2017-12-18 21:49:30",
  "date_gmt":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
  "content":"",
  "status":"draft",
  "comment_status":"open",
  "image":""}

for items in product_list.values():
    new_list = [new_product_dict]
    items.append(new_list)
print(items)
```

this approach works for me, of course you can add more dicts in the for loop